# Is it possible to save a file using client side javascript in xpages

Tags: xpages

I customize my confirmation prompt using sweetAlert, I did it, now my problem is using a customize confirmation prompt, I cannot use SSJS code but I need to save a document with a file upload.

I need Help with this thanks!

Comment: You need to post the code you have so far and you need to be very specific about: what your interaction model looks like, what you tried and how your data is structured. And you can't "save" a document using client script. You can post to the server which then saves using form.submit() or some Ajax

Answer (score 1):

My workaround for this is an XPoages button that contains the required SSJS code for saving the document. The button resides in a hidden normal DIV (style="display:none"). When executing you CSJS just refer to the clientId of that button and fire the event click() like in

```
function csjsAction(){
    dojo.byId("#{id:yourButton}").click();
}
```